# MySQL Cast to Float or What Decimal value

Tags: mysql, sql-server, type-conversion, floating-point-precision

I develop software for an insurance environment, so decimal values are very important.
We are converting from MSSQL to MYSQL. The query my question relates to is:

```
SELECT CAST(
    CAST(
      (initialpremium - totalpremium) / 2 * 
      CAST(premiummultiplier AS INT) 
    AS FLOAT) 
FROM policy 
/* rest of the query... */
```

This code works in MSSQL but not in MYSQL.
[This is valid cast types for mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html).

The question that I have therefor is, is what is the correct decimal length for float.
[This link does not help. But describes converting from float to real in MSSQL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx) and I have searched for [float datasize mssql](https://www.google.co.za/search?q=float%20datasize%20mssql&oq=float%20datasize%20mssql&aqs=chrome..69i57.4115j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) on the internet.

Comment: I found an answer. Instead of specifying decimal values in mysql you can just change the code to cast(value as DECIMAL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer. Instead of specifying decimal values in mysql you can just change the code to cast(value as DECIMAL)

Answer (score 2):

MySQL can cast integers to floats by adding `0.0`:

```
SELECT
    integer_column + 0.0 AS float_column
```

Answer (score -1):

```sql
select integer_column::float from tablename;
```

Comment: The `::float` is a shorthand cast found in PostgreSQL. The OP's question is about MySQL, which does not have that.