Adding decimal places in a select query to a sum
I have built a select query which utilises the SUM function and I'm trying to make the output show with 2 decimal places for the Settlement amount. In this example the actual STTL_AMOUNT is 29999 but I'd like it to output 299.99 so I need to add a decimal place in before the last 2 numbers. The format for STTL_AMOUNT is number(22,4)
SELECT COUNT (STTL_AMOUNT) as "COUNT",
   SUM(STTL_AMOUNT) - SUM(CASE WHEN IS_REVERSAL =1 THEN STTL_AMOUNT ELSE 0 End ) as "Settlement Amount",
   HOST_DATE as "Settlement Date"
   FROM  OPR_OPERATION
   WHERE    MCC = '6011'
   AND      MSG_TYPE ='MSGTPRES'
   AND      HOST_DATE >= TRUNC( SYSDATE )
   GROUP BY HOST_DATE;

And I get the output below:
"COUNT" "Settlement Amount" "Settlement Date"
1   29999   24-MAY-24

But I would like it to output as this:
"COUNT" "Settlement Amount" "Settlement Date"
1   299.99  24-MAY-24

I was wondering if I should use to_char, but I can't seem to get the query to work at all if I try that.

maybe this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23105323/mysql-cast-to-float-or-what-decimal-value

and if you divide by 100... `(SUM(STTL_AMOUNT) - SUM(CASE WHEN IS_REVERSAL =1 THEN STTL_AMOUNT ELSE 0 End ))/100  The problem isn't that decimals aren't showing the problem is likely your data type is stored w/o decimal and you need to shift it.  dividing by 100 should do that in this case.  Though it seems odd amounts wouldn't be stored with their decimals.  So what data type is STTL_Amount?    Perhaps it needs to be cast to decimal with scale and precision?  When dealing with currency or precision, decimal is preffered.

ok seeing that / 100 didn't work... what are your NLS settings in SQL Developer (Assuming your seeing the results in that or Toad or similar..)  This sounds like a display issue in rendering the results; not a bad value being retruned...  Possibly this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571355/nls-numeric-characters-setting-for-decimal

if I run in SQL Developer: select value
from nls_session_parameters
where parameter = 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS'; i can see the value . , returned

You should be able to simplify your query by swapping the THEN and ELSE clauses in the CASE expression and dividing by 100 to:
SELECT COUNT (STTL_AMOUNT) as "COUNT",
       SUM(CASE WHEN IS_REVERSAL = 1 THEN 0 ELSE STTL_AMOUNT/100 END)
         as "Settlement Amount",
       HOST_DATE as "Settlement Date"
FROM   OPR_OPERATION
WHERE  MCC = '6011'
AND    MSG_TYPE ='MSGTPRES'
AND    HOST_DATE >= TRUNC( SYSDATE )
GROUP BY HOST_DATE;

The division should be able to inside or outside the CASE or SUM:
SUM(CASE WHEN IS_REVERSAL = 1 THEN 0 ELSE STTL_AMOUNT END/100)

or
SUM(CASE WHEN IS_REVERSAL = 1 THEN 0 ELSE STTL_AMOUNT END)/100

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE opr_operation (host_date, sttl_amount, is_reversal, mcc, msg_type) AS
  SELECT SYSDATE, 29999, 0, '6011', 'MSGTPRES' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT SYSDATE - INTERVAL '1' SECOND, 20000, 0, '6011', 'MSGTPRES' FROM DUAL;

Should all output:



COUNT
Settlement Amount
Settlement Date




1
299.99
2024-05-24 21:23:20


1
200
2024-05-24 21:23:19



If you want to display the value with two decimal places then use TO_CHAR:
SELECT COUNT (STTL_AMOUNT) as "COUNT",
       TO_CHAR(
         SUM(CASE WHEN IS_REVERSAL = 1 THEN 0 ELSE STTL_AMOUNT/100 END),
         'fm99999999999999999990.00'
       ) as "Settlement Amount",
       HOST_DATE as "Settlement Date"
FROM   OPR_OPERATION
WHERE  MCC = '6011'
AND    MSG_TYPE ='MSGTPRES'
AND    HOST_DATE >= TRUNC( SYSDATE )
GROUP BY HOST_DATE;

Outputs:



COUNT
Settlement Amount
Settlement Date




1
299.99
2024-05-24 21:23:20


1
200.00
2024-05-24 21:23:19



fiddle

Thanks @MT0 - I've tried numerous things now including your suggestion above and that has worked thanks. However, I've tried a few different values though and if I only use 20000 in sttl_amount it doesn't show any decimal places when I run the query and just outputs as 200 is there any way that I can make it show the 2 decimal places to be 200.00 ?

@headspace Updated, if you want to format the value to show 2d.p. then use TO_CHAR.

Just divide by 100 and round to remove unnecessary 0's?
SELECT COUNT (STTL_AMOUNT) as "COUNT",
       ROUND(CAST(SUM(STTL_AMOUNT) - SUM(CASE WHEN IS_REVERSAL =1 THEN STTL_AMOUNT ELSE 0 End ) AS FLOAT) / 100,2) as "Settlement Amount",
       HOST_DATE as "Settlement Date"
       FROM  OPR_OPERATION
       WHERE    MCC = '6011'
       AND      MSG_TYPE ='MSGTPRES'
       AND      HOST_DATE >= TRUNC( SYSDATE )
       GROUP BY HOST_DATE;


Thanks - I just tried that but I still get the same output come out as 29999 rather than 299.99

I edited the answer to cast to float before the division.

Thanks @patm that now just gives me an output as "COUNT" "Settlement Amount" "Settlement Date"
1   299  24-MAY-24 so still not formatting correctly.
